# :hover pseudoclass doesn't work with universal selector *

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

If I write

```
h1:hover, li:hover {color:green;}
```

Both h1 and li elements get the hover effect.

Buf if I write:

```
*:hover {color: green;}
```

This has effect only on anchor elements.

Does :hover pseudoclass not work with universal selector?

Comment: I beg to differ: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/VW6gD

Comment: Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: I was testing on google chrome (10.x) as well as IE 8.

Comment: @Bolt, placing my code on jsfiddle seems to make it work. But the same code run independently doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work. The catch is that **all the text** on your page ends up turning green because the `body` element is also matched, so you don't see a "mouse-over" effect as long as your cursor is anywhere on the viewport (i.e. the page body). You can work around this either by not using the universal selector (I mean, why would you?) or by specifying a `body:hover` color.

If you see a hover effect only on `a` elements, you probably have an `a:hover` style somewhere that's overriding your `*:hover` style as the universal selector is less specific than a type selector (that is, not specific at all). But the rest of your text should always be green until you take the cursor out of the viewport, for instance by moving it to the browser chrome or away from the window. (Note that the "viewport" in the fiddle I link to in my comment is an iframe.)

Comment: body:hover does work. I was just experimenting to see whether *:hover works or not. body:hover {color: red;} *:hover {color: green;} together have the effect of body getting red on hover, while anchors getting green on hover. I didn't set a:hover anywhere. Just one test CSS and test html (posted on ur fiddle page)

Comment: Interestingly body:hover doesn't seem to work on IE8 while it works on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you talking about? Neutralising `html:hover` and `body:hover` demonstrates that the remaining elements change accordingly on hover, in Chrome at least and I'm sure any other modern browser.

### Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/cTpxS](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/cTpxS/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shailesh/GFp5X/  it works on jsfiddle.net. But if you use the same files as meerkat.html and meerkat.css and run standalone it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Shailesh Kumar: Still looks fine to me in [this independent file](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Marcel/cTpxS/show/light/).